# SQL Re-sorting the result of a query

Tags: sql, sorting

Looking for some help, to re-order the result of a query.

So I have a table that contains just two columns ID, Tag.

Sample data:

```
1, France
2, Germany
3, Spain
4, USA
5, Spain
... and so on
```

I use a query to pull out the five most popular tags:

```
SELECT COUNT(ItemID) as tagcount, tag
FROM TagTable
GROUP BY Tag
order by tagcount desc
limit 0, 5
```

This works well and gives an output, for example:

```
49, France
47, USA
42, Italy
39, England
38, Portugal
```

However, after plucking the "top 5", I'd like the output to be alphabetical, eg:

```
39, England
49, France
42, Italy
38, Portugal
47, USA
```

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (For future readers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it into one more select:

```sql
select * from (
    SELECT COUNT( ItemID) as tagcount, tag
    FROM TagTable
    GROUP BY Tag
    order by tagcount desc
    limit 0,5
) t1
order by tag
```

Comment: Perfect, so easy too, thank you so much.